# Rained on Sony Vaio Laptop screens black

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sony-vaio, water-damage

So I left windows open while i was gone for a few days, my laptop happened to be underneath them. It rained and got my laptop wet except it was plugged in, it didn't short out wasn't that wet at all. That night i dried the cd drive and anything i could, that was possible. only water really seemed to be in the seem at the edge of the laptop by my mouse pad. So i tipped it to let water run out. It turned on and the screen worked and everything. Next morning laptop turns on but now my screen is just black. Is my laptop toast or is there an easy none expensive way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try vacuuming ports and holes, it sometimes helps to suck some water out. Some websites may suggest using hair dryer on the laptop, but it's not a good idea.

Another DIY method is to leave the laptop in dry rice over night. Rice is hygroscopic and will absorb water.

If none of these will work, you'll probably have to let professionals handle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how, You can actually pull the laptop apart and check it for Moisture internally, You'll probably find that there is water in the Port where the Monitor Connects the ribbon cable to the Mainboard,

But, if you've never changed a laptop monitor or don't know how to pull them apart, Consult an Expert, and even then, Make sure he actually knows how to do it and isn't just taking a crack at it to get the service fee.